# The execute order differ from code order

Tags: go, goland

I execute this code snippet in goland IDE but found the output order is NOTthe same as what I expected:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "errors"
)

func main() {

    println("===========================")
    println("---------------------------")
    r,_:= div(6,3)
    fmt.Println(r)
}

func div(x, y int) (int, error) {
    defer println("dispose...")
    if y == 0 {
        return 0, errors.New("division by zero")
    }
    return x / y, nil
}
```

output:

[image]

1. why the out order is differ from code order
2. why the output in different color(white & red), I use goland IDE by jetbrain

I could not reproduce in https://play.golang.org/p/2T5LOt7FRDn
My Local env: windows 10 + go1.10.3 windows/amd64 + GoLand 2018.1.4

Comment: Try run `go clean` and see if the problem re-occur. If it does, run the code out of IDE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, note that `println()` writes to `os.Stderr`.

https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#println

> ...and writes the result to standard error

It seems Jetbrain's IDEs would show you `Stderr` lines at the end and in a different colour.

This is a smaller program that would let you reproduce the same behaviour:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "to stderr")
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, "to stdout")
}
```

You will see the output inverted, with the `to stderr` line shown in red.

You cannot reproduce this outside the IDE cause then stderr and stdout ouput will be interleaved.